# Pipeline convert mp3 -> sink with gstreamer

Tags: audio, mp3, gstreamer, pipeline

I tryed to make a pipeline to convert a mp3 file to a sink but it does not work.

What I tried :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp3  ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! appsink caps=audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=48000 name=sink
```

When I put the sink in a .wav file after, its not recognized at .wav and when I open it in audacity raw data it's just noise.
I can't use filesink because I need to use the sink for some purpose unrelated.

My best guess is that my pipeline is wrong, if someone has an idea,  don't hesitate to ask me question !

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline was wrong as expected.

The correct pipeline was :

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myfile.mp3  ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! capsfilter caps="audio/xraw,format=S16LE,rate=48000,channel=2" ! appsink name=sink`